# Using Profiles in ASP.NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-profiles

Im new to using Profiles in vb.net and trying to figure out what im doing wrong. In webconfig I have the following code:

And in my vb code i'm trying to add to the profile by using this code:

```
 profile.FirstName = "John"
```

But I keep getting an error saying:

> FirstName is not a member of profile.

Is there something im doing wrong?. I am trying to learn this through reading this book but it seems like there missing a step. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you define a ProfileProvider in your Web.Config such as [SqlProfileProvider](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.profile.sqlprofileprovider.aspx) or the [Table Profile Provider](http://www.asp.net/downloads/sandbox/table-profile-provider-samples)

Here an example, replace the `YOURConnectionString` and `YOURApplicationName` with string you use.

```
<profile defaultProvider="CustomProfileProvider" enabled="true">
        <providers>
           <add name="CustomProfileProvider"
                type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider"
                connectionStringName="YOURConnectionString"
                applicationName="YOURApplicationName"
                description="Something" />
        </providers>
        <properties>
           <add name="FirstName" type="System.String"/>
        </properties>
</profile>
```

You could also read this [Article](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020111657/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/101106-1.aspx)